# need to disable Night Shift. How?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, night-shift

For the life of me I can't figure out how to turn nightshift off.

I can't do any video editing / photo processing!

I tried ticking Manual, which only turns it.... *ON?*

Am I missing something?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Are you certain you're seeing Night Shift, not just Auto-brightness, or even True Tone, which should also be off for calibrated colour work?

A quick workaround for anything that has a schedule you can't seem to get completely away from is to set it to work between e.g. 1 & 2am - so it's on but you're never using it at that time.

Comment: It's definitely tinting the monitor yellow. Not brightness. Neat trick for the schedule thanks :) I'll try and see what happens once it gets dark.